Jenkins pipelines sharing something common without Sharing Libraries feature
Say I got two different jenkin files in the same project doing different things. These two jenkins files share something in common (like a stage). I hope to extract this stage into a groovy file and make the two jenkins files somehow include/import the groovy file. Is it possible to do this WITHOUT the Shared Libraries feature?
I'm preferring to using declarative pipelines. Thanks.
Currently, I can do it like this but I don't think it's very elegant.
// test.groovy
def Call() {
    println "Hello World"
}
return this

def modules = [:]

pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('before') {
            steps {
                echo 'Before!'
            }
        }
        stage('common') {
            steps {
                script {
                    modules.whatever = load "workspace/relative/path/to/test.groovy"
                    modules.whatever.Call()
                }
            }
        }
        stage('after') {
            steps {
                echo 'After!'
            }
        }
    }
}



extract this stage into a groovy file and make the two jenkins files somehow include/import the groovy file.. This is exactly what a jenkins shared library does. You extract a block of code into a groovy file, then import it into a different file. Any reason you don't want to use a feature that is specifically built for a case like this?

@MB Seems shared libraries require separate SCM repo and a specific folder structure, which seems to heavy for my use case.

Since shared libraries are too "heavy" and loading a Groovy file and invoking a method is too "inelegant" it is ambiguous what solution in the spectrum between the two would be acceptable.

@MatthewSchuchard In my example above, the stage was included as a script. I'll be happy if I can put the whole stage in the groovy file.
